# How to set CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE in RHEL 6.4 (linux)

Tags: linux, rhel, linux-kernel

I am trying to tune the RHEL6.4 Kernel to handle server style load for of my application. With RHEL 6 scheduler has been changed to CFS and with RHEL 5 my application works fine. I would like change the preemptive option of the kernel to none. I don't know if changing this value in `/boot/config-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64` will work or not.

In addition I want to set the value to set in the `kernel.sched_features` for disabling preempt using the `sysctl` command.

Comment: `/boot/config-*` is provided for your reference so you can see how the kernel was configured at compile time. Changing it won't enable or disable anything. What is the specific problem are you trying to address? If you're worried about processor time, have you looked into moving the processes over to the real time scheduler via `chrt`?